# Change height of GradientDrawable as textview background programmatically

Tags: java, android, shapes

I modify height of GradientDrawable by setBounds().

I got a good shape for my textview.

but the height of textview has been changed too.

what can I do just only make higher for shape?

[image](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1GmX-q4lZcJgGHVE7k6Vl2HkSJE7IpeAT)

```
private Drawable getTagBackground(int iColor, final int iTextViewWidth, final int iTextViewHeight) {
    final float RATIO_SHAPE_WIDTH = 1.5f;
    final float RATIO_SHAPE_HEIGHT = 2.3f;
    final int STROKE_WIDTH = 3;
    final float CORNER_RADIUS = 40f;

    GradientDrawable gd = new GradientDrawable() {
        @Override
        public int getIntrinsicWidth() {
            return (int)(super.getIntrinsicWidth() * RATIO_SHAPE_WIDTH);
        }

        @Override
        public int getIntrinsicHeight() {
            return (int)(super.getIntrinsicHeight() * RATIO_SHAPE_HEIGHT);
        }
    };
    gd.setShape(GradientDrawable.RECTANGLE);
    gd.setSize(iTextViewWidth, iTextViewHeight);
    gd.setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    gd.setStroke(STROKE_WIDTH, iColor);
    gd.setCornerRadius(CORNER_RADIUS);
    //gd.setBounds(0, 0, iTextViewWidth, iTextViewHeight * 2);

    return gd;
}
```

Comment: image posted, right side shape in the image I want, it's just a little adjustment that make shape look more good.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be to have an ImageView behind your TextView and making height changes in that ImageView.